# Function to check if entered Product Name is unique

Tags: c

I am trying to develop a function which checks if the entered Product Name already exists in file, using strcmp().

This is my function, which then I call it from the void AddProduct() function when the system asks the user to enter the Product Name. The problem is that the function is not working well, whenever the user inputs a new Product Name, it keeps saying that it already exists.

```
bool ProductUnique(char ProductName)
{


      product p;
        bool uniqueproduct = true;
        char productname[50];

        pfp=fopen("products.dat","rb");

    while(1)
    {
    fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,pfp);

    if(feof(pfp))
    {
    break;
    }
    if(strcmp(productname,p.ProductName)==0)
    {
        uniqueproduct = false;
    }
    if(!uniqueproduct)
    {
        printf("Product Name aleady exists!");
    }
    }
    return uniqueproduct;
    fclose(pfp);
}
```

And this is part of my void AddProduct() function

```
void addProduct()
{
    product p1;


    pfp=fopen("products.dat","ab");

    printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\t Adding a Product\n\n");
    printf("========================================================\n\n");


    char ProductName[100];
    do
    {
        printf("Enter Product Name: \n");
        scanf("%s",ProductUnique(p1.ProductName);
    }while(!ProductUnique(p1.ProductName));
```

Comment: Why on Earth you are closing the file after returning from your function?

Answer (score 0):

You never set the value for `productname`. Also it seems you have confused the input parameter to the function. I think it should be `ProductUnique(const char* productname)` and then you should not have a product name variable in the function body.

EDIT: here is the fixed code at least the errors I found. I have added `CHANGED` annotations to see what I've changed.

```
bool ProductUnique(const char* productname) // CHANGED: FIX THE ARGUMENT
{


      product p;
        bool uniqueproduct = true;
        // char productname[50];  // CHANGED: NOT NEEDED.

        pfp=fopen("products.dat","rb");

    while(1)
    {
    fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,pfp);

    if(feof(pfp))
    {
    break;
    }
    if(strcmp(productname,p.ProductName)==0)
    {
        uniqueproduct = false;
    }
    if(!uniqueproduct)
    {
        printf("Product Name aleady exists!");
    }
    }
    fclose(pfp); // CHANGED: SHOULD CLOSE BEFORE RETURN
    return uniqueproduct;
//    fclose(pfp);  // CHANGED: DON"T DO ANYTHING AFTER RETURN
}
```

AddProduct() function

```
void addProduct()
{
    product p1;


    pfp=fopen("products.dat","ab");

    printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\t Adding a Product\n\n");
    printf("========================================================\n\n");


    //     char ProductName[100]; // CHANGED: NOT NEEDED
    do
    {
        printf("Enter Product Name: \n");
        scanf("%s",&p1.ProductName); // CHANGED: READ INPUT, DON'T CALL FUNCTION HERE.
    }while(!ProductUnique(p1.ProductName));
```

Comment: What do you mean by setting the value for productname? Also, I can't figure out what input parameter I should include. I think that's the reason why the function is not working properly. Sorry, but I'm a beginner in C programming.

Comment: @JessicaButtigieg productname is declared as local variable in your function and you never modify it, so it remains uninitialized. I imagine you meant to use the function's argument which is called ProductName and is also of the wrong type char instead of char **array** or **a pointer** to char.

Comment: I arranged the input parameter to ProductUnique(const char* productname) but it is giving me the error: conflicting types for 'ProductUnique'

Comment: @JessicaButtigieg did you also change the **decalration** of the function?

Comment: Yes, I changed it now but this time it's giving me the error: 'productname' redeclared as different kind of symbol

Comment: @JessicaButtigieg because you did not remove the local variable from the function. I have added the fixed code in my answer, please take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, the function is now working but it seems that the whole product record is not being saved in file due to the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

This part should be outside of `while`

```
 if(!uniqueproduct)
 {
    printf("Product Name aleady exists!");
 }
```

So your code should look like:

```
while(1)
{
fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,pfp);

if(feof(pfp))
{
break;
}
if(strcmp(productname,p.ProductName)==0)
{
    uniqueproduct = false;
}
}//from while

if(!uniqueproduct)
{
    printf("Product Name aleady exists!");
}
fclose(pfp);
return uniqueproduct;
```